# phpmyadmin not showing content after upgrade (phpmyadmin5, Ubuntu20.04 with php8.1)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, php-8

So my issue as follows. Recently I found lots of warnings and deprecation notices I then ran the following which has removed the messages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade phpmyadmin
```

However when i now login the database list briefly flashes up in the left sidebar before being removed. I'm able to change the tabs in the top of the page but no content is shown in the content region, see screenshot:
[image]

I looked in the logs and had a message about the permissions of the blowfish file so I amended this to use www-data but this made no difference except now i get no new error at all in the error.log file.

All my dev sites connected to this database are working but i can't view or amend any tables from phpmyadmin. I have restarted Apache (`sudo service apache2 restart`) Any ideas?

Comment: I am also facing this issue after I upgraded my PHP from 7.4 to 8.0. If I downgrade PHP to 7.4, it works. I want phpmyadmin to function correctly with PHP 8.0 as well. I am not sure what and where the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I switched from php7.4 to php8 a big error in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` showed up, that the in `/usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1140` was an error.

change `$service = null === $r->getConstructor() ? $r->newInstance() : $r->newInstanceArgs($arguments);` to `$service = null === $r->getConstructor() ? $r->newInstance() : $r->newInstanceArgs(array_values($arguments));` do the trick.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/symfony/+bug/1932552
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/8e34978e4e2c4bf7dac97e44e904368c4cfb54f8